# multiple lxc containers sharing the same CPU and mem resource pool

Tags: lxc

I'm using lxc via libvirt on centos 7.
Is there a way to configure multiple containers to share the same resource pool?

I need this for 2 resource intensive containers. Right now I configured the resources to be over-committed. Usually the 2 containers will not be run simultaneously. However, when they run at the same time I want to prevent out of memory scenarios affecting the whole system and hard to track bugs.